# CoreData inserting new object for entity is giving me error when using setValue: forKey: with an int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Here is the code:

```
ComicDB * newComic = (ComicDB *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ComicDB" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [newComic setValue:comic.iComicId forKey:@"ComicID"];
            [newComic setValue:comic.sImage forKey:@"Image"];
            [newComic setValue:comic.sName forKey:@"Name"];
            [newComic setValue:comic.sText forKey:@"Text"];
            [newComic setValue:comic.sComicURL forKey:@"URL"];
```

This was the warning i got on the `setValue:comic.iComicId forKey@"ComicID"`. FYI - comic is my own class that holds comic details.
warning: passing argument 1 of 'setValue:forKey:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

when i change the line of code to:

```
[newComic setValue:[comic.iComicId intValue] forKey:@"ComicID"];
```

i get these warnings and an error:
warning: invalid receiver type 'int'
warning: passing argument 1 of 'setValue:forKey:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `comic.iComicId` is not an `NSNumber`, you need to wrap it in an `NSNumber` object then pass it:

```
[newComic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[comic.iComicId intValue]] forKey:@"ComicID"];
```

Comment: comic.iComicId is a @property (nonatomic, assign) int iComicId; where as my ComicDB * newComic - ComicID is a NSNumber. I had to use this to make it work: [newComic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:comic.iComicId] forKey:@"ComicID"];