# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC error

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax-error

While programming in Objective-C, I came upon the error stated above. I was trying to have a variable save into a core data file that could be accessed later.

```
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newDevice setValue:timeTick forKey:@"name"];
[newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
[newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
```

TimeTick is my variable and that is the line where the error occurs. Any ideas as to why this is occurring, and possible solutions?

Comment: What is the declaration of timeTick?

Comment: You're not programming "in Xcode". You are programming in Objective-C, and the error comes from the compiler. The IDE used is irrelevant (so is the compiler, by the way) -- if you make a semantical or syntactic error, it will be an error no matter what tools you are using.

Comment: The error is occurring because you're trying to pass an integer, `timeTick` as an argument that needs to be an object. The compiler starts to try to convert the one to the other, then realizes that this isn't allowed and tells you so.

Comment: There are any number of similar questions on SO that should point you in the right direction here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101715/integer-to-nsinteger-and-save-to-core-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886160/setting-the-value-of-a-double-attribute-on-nsmanagedobject, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638079/coredata-inserting-new-object-for-entity-is-giving-me-error-when-using-setvalue all contain the answer.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick response! Will changing timeTick to a string and having that as the new value work? @JoshCaswell